# When does the name prefix "Mc" take stress?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, names, surnames

*Mc* (or *Mac*) is often used as a prefix in Gaelic-derived names.

In one class containing most such names, prefixing *Mc* does not affect the position of the accent somewhere on the base name. Thus *Mc* is unstressed. For example:

- McDonald /mɛkˈdɑnl̩d/
- MacArthur /mɛkˈarθr̩/
- McCoy /mɛk̚ˈkoj/
- McGill /mɛˈɡɪl/
- McMahon /mɛkˈmæn/
- McCarthy
- McLeod
- McDonnell
- McCormack
- McEwan
- McAllister
- McOrmond
- <del>McNuggets</del>

But sometimes *Mc* takes stress:

- McIntosh /ˈmækɪntɑʃ/
- McIntyre /ˈmækɪntajr̩/
- McAfee /ˈmækəfi/
- McAvoy /ˈmækəvoj/

All of these I could think of contain a vowel-initial base name, but that's not a sufficient condition.

How can you determine which class a particular name belongs to, and what is the etymological reason for the distinction?

Comment: I would argue that the stress is on the *Mac* part of *MacArthur*, or at least that *Mac* and *Ar* have almost equal stress.  Note that the base name of your stressed examples start with vowel -- this might be the difference.

Comment: @cornbreadninja: 'McIntosh' is the only one for me that has the stress on the 'mc'. (even though I realize that many stress 'McAfee' on the first, that neer sounds natural to me (as a plain old AmE speaker)).

Comment: @cornbreadninja: But that's not a sufficient condition for being in the stressed class.

Comment: Proper names are not subject to general constraints on stress, in the first place, and prefixes from other languages are even less so. There's no regularity here to express with rules.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail that is why I said *might*, and commented rather than answered.

Comment: Check this: http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/06/joe-mc-what.html

Comment: @RainDoctor: Good find. Make that an answer!

Answer (score 6):

Check this: *John Wells’s phonetic blog,* "[Joe Mc-what?](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/06/joe-mc-what.html)"

> the prefix *M(a)c-* means ‘son of’ in Irish and Scottish Gaelic. The general rule is that
>
> - before a stressed syllable it is pronounced **mək**, or in a more formal style perhaps **mæk**; thus *McBride, McDonald, McEwan, McPherson*
> - before an unstressed syllable it is **mæk**, and is itself stressed; thus *McAnulty* **ˌmækəˈnʌlti**, *McAvoy* **ˈmækəvɔɪ**, *McEnroe, McIntosh, McNamara*
> - but before **k** or **g** it is reduced to **mə**, thus *McCarthy* **məˈkɑː(r)θi,** *McCorquodale, McGill, McGonagall, McQueen.*
>
> The problem with *McElderry,* and with several other names of three or more syllables, is knowing whether the second syllable is stressed or not.

There is more information in the blog post and the comments below.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's just a case of a family name being pronounced as a family prefers to pronounce it, as well as the tendency to slur or shorten common words (such as m'lady for "my lady"), but there is one interesting aspect of Gaelic designations that may apply.

In Gaelic, *Mac* means "son" or "son of" and is pronounced Mack (as the "Mc" in McIntosh.)
*Mhic* means "wife of the son of" and is pronounced as the "Mc" in McCoy. A woman with the given name of Niamh who married a man named Colm Mac Intosh would then be known as Niamh Mhic Intosh.

Comment: I've heard that 'mhic' was [also for grandfather](http://medievalscotland.org/scotnames/quickgaelicbynames/#complexbyname) (like "O'").

Comment: Been a while since I was in Ireland, but if I remember correctly, Mac = Son of, O'= grandson (or great-grandson, or great-great etc), Bean Mhic (shortned to Mhic) = wife of the son of and Nic = unmarried daughter of. I think there's a feminine version of O' as well, but I don't remember what it is.